# Create a command for header titles

Tags: macros, header-footer

how can i be able to create this one by simply making this into command?

ouput:

```
\begin{center}
\myname{Mike Backlund}
\myschool{School 1}
\myschool{School 2}
\end{center}
```

display would be:

> ```
>                             Mike Backlund
>                                 School1
>                                 School2
> ```

Hope you could help me

Answer (score 2):

I provide two possible and simple solutions. The first disregards from your three commands `\myname` and `\myschool` and makes one new command with three input variables. the second uses three input variables `\myname`, `\myschoolone` and `\myschooltwo`. The MWE will provide two identical layouts using these two approached.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Single command
\newcommand{\myheader}[3]{
\begin{center}
#1\\ #2\\ #3
\end{center}
}
% defining three variables
\newcommand{\myname}{Mike Backlund}
\newcommand{\myschoolone}{School 1}
\newcommand{\myschooltwo}{School 2}


\begin{document}

% alternative 1:
\myheader{Mike Backlund}{School 1}{School 2}
\vskip5mm % just to separate them a bit

% alternative 2:
\myheader{\myname}{\myschoolone}{\myschooltwo}

\end{document}
```

Since it is possible to feed the header macro with both commands and text, you could mix them as well. I assume that you want the name and school definitions so that you can use them elsewehere in the document which makes the second approach more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 'the' header, you could do this with `fancyhdr` (or perhaps with your documentclass's facilities):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myname}{Mike Backlund}
\newcommand{\schooli}{School 1}
\newcommand{\schoolii}{School 2}

\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{\myname\\\schooli\\\schoolii}% or in one of the other fancyhdr locations
\lhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% uncomment to 'remove' line below header

\begin{document}

\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```